# Javascript FORTNITE API request

Tags: javascript, html, api

today i started learning js with api and i want to ask how to fix this.

I registred on fortnite tracker and created api.

api is like:

```
GET https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/{platform}/{epic-nickname}
```

and api key is like:

```
TRN-Api-Key: xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx
```

I found something here that i need to do it:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.request("GET", "api", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('TRN-Api-Key' "KEY");
xhttp.send();
```

but when i do it like this, it will show me error CORS and i don't know how ti fix that.

Thanks <3

Comment: You cannot request that API from clientside js. Use serverside code.

Comment: @JonasWilms and how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found solution for this api so i looked for other apis.

i found Fortnite api by https://fortniteapi.com/

name api is:

```
https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/id?username=YOUR_NAME
```

example name api:

```
https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/id?username=Ninja
```

there you get UID. You copy that UID and place it to this api with platfrom (pc,ps4)

```
https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/public/br_stats?user_id=UID&platform=pc
```

example stats api:

```
https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/public/br_stats?user_id=4735ce9132924caf8a5b17789b40f79c&platform=pc
```

JS CODE:

```js
/*  your uid and platform  */
let uid = "4735ce9132924caf8a5b17789b40f79c";
let platform = "pc";

/*  fortnite api link provided by <fortniteapi.com>  */
let statApi = "https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/users/public/br_stats?user_id=" + uid + "&platform=" + platform;

httpRequestAsync(statApi, theResponse);

/*  getting response from API and defining variables   */
function theResponse(response){
  console.log("getting stats of "  + uid);
  let jsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
  //example of getting data from api
  console.log("Name: " + jsonObject.username);
  console.log("Wins: " + jsonObject.totals.wins);
  console.log("Kills: " + jsonObject.totals.kills);
  console.log("K/D: " + jsonObject.totals.kd);
  console.log("Matches: " + jsonObject.totals.matchesplayed);
  console.log("Winrate: " + jsonObject.totals.winrate + "%");
};

/*  sending XMLHHttpRequest api  */
function httpRequestAsync(api, callback){
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200)
    callback(httpRequest.responseText);
  }
  httpRequest.open("GET", api, true);
  httpRequest.send();
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

hope that will help someone

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to set these headers to allow cors origin

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.request("GET", "api", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
xhttp.setRequestHeader('TRN-Api-Key' "KEY");
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: These headers would need to be set serverside (api.fortnitetracker.com), not in his Client JS.

Comment: It still says: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/Ninja' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.