# Why can't add headers to axios.get?

Tags: api, vue.js, http-headers, axios

I'm using axios and vue.js to play with the Fortnite Tracker API.
In their documentation it's clearly said that we need to include the "TRN-Api-Key" in header.

I tested with Postman and It works.

And this is my axios function to make the request:

```
let url = `https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/${this.platform}/${this.username}`;
// username and platform are from my Vue Component.
   axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        "TRN-Api-Key": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" // of course from my account on their website.
      }
   })
       .then(response => console.log(response.data))
```

I expect the output in json like in Postman but I had a 404 Error: "Network Error".

And in the Browser Network Debug I can't see the request header 'TRN-Api-Key'.

[EDIT]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full server response please (where you got the 404)

Comment: I had the 404 on the first OPTIONS request.

Comment: Does the server you're contacting support CORS? The `OPTIONS` request is a CORS pre-flight request and the response headers you've posted don't give any indication that it supports CORS.

Comment: I don't know about the server I know only that is a public API! And in Postman it works I had my json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is running on a server you can write a short `PHP`-Script and use `curl` in it to access the API (I think it's even possible to generate `PHP`code from Postman).
Just address this script with axios and submit your `platform` and `username`properties to build the right url.

Or have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388398/javascript-fortnite-api-request) alternatively. Maybe the use of an other API like @kecinotrab provided in the acceptet answer will help you too.

Comment: I tested with `curl` and it worked! Like mentioned in the post in your comment that this API don't accept requests from clientside.